# Compile Google-Maps-IOS-Utils into Nativescript

Tags: ios, nativescript, google-maps-ios-utils

can someone help me please:

I'm trying to add **Google-Maps-IOS-Utils** to my project , but I'm having issues.

Basically I just need the following class to be available in my project: "**GMSGeometryUtils**"

If **installing from Podfile** (by plugin), it will result in following issue:

```
The 'Pods-exampleapp' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries: (/Documents/example/example-app/platforms/ios/Pods/GoogleMaps/Base/Frameworks/GoogleMapsBase.framework, /Documents/example/example-app/platforms/ios/Pods/GoogleMaps/Maps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework, and /Documents/example/example-app/platforms/ios/Pods/GoogleMaps/Maps/Frameworks/GoogleMapsCore.framework)
```

I'm wondering if the following solution can be applied on my app, or something else needs to be done: https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/issues/17#issuecomment-246993764

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that solution could work. I think compiler will pick your `.h` / `.m` files if you add them to your `platforms/ios/src` directory.

Comment: So, should I copy/paste the whole library src (https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/tree/master/src) into platforms/ios/src?

Is there a way to do this by a plugin, since this will involve doing a manual thing everytime I delete platforms folder, which is often done after plugin install , etc

Comment: I meant the `platforms/ios/src` within your plugin only.

Comment: Hi @Manoj, thanks for following, I'm new creating a plugin, could you help pointing me in the right direction? I've created this repo https://github.com/victorevox/nativescript-google-maps-ios-utils/tree/master/src/platforms/ios/Google-Maps-IOS-Utils, as you could see I'm adding files inside **platforms/ios/Google-Maps-IOS-Utils** but it seems is not working as when you run the app, the class is not available at runtime